# Why *ngFor in angular not printing the last value that is entered by the push method

Tags: angular, lifecycle

I don't know why logs i.e string array is not printing it's value "on Destroy--child" in list item `<li *ngFor="let log of logs"><code>{{ log }}</code></li>` and the same string array prints correctly "On Destroy--child" in `{{ logs.join(', ') }}`.
 
 That means value is inserted in array, what is the reason it's not printing??
plz explain, i am totally confused.

link for same example: http://plnkr.co/edit/kBHV6AximaHAC26kYEOA?p=gitter 

open this link and run it.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
      <h5>Lifecycle Events Log</h5>
      {{ logs.join(', ') }}

      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let log of logs">
          <code>{{ log }}</code>
        </li>
      </ul>


      <app-child 
        *ngIf="showChild" 
        [name]="name"
        (log)="onLog($event)">
      </app-child>
    `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Alice';
  logs: string[] = [];
  showChild = true;

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => this.updateName(), 3000);
    setTimeout(() => this.hideChild(), 4000);
  }

  updateName() {
    this.name = 'Bob';
  }

  hideChild() {
    this.showChild = false;
    this.logs.push(`onDestroy--app`);
  }

  onLog(data) {
    this.logs.push(data);
  }

}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  Output,
  SimpleChange,
  OnChanges, 
  OnInit,
  DoCheck,
  AfterContentInit,
  AfterContentChecked,
  AfterViewInit,
  AfterViewChecked,
  OnDestroy,
  EventEmitter
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    template: `
      <div>
        <h4>Child Component</h4>
        <p>{{ name }}</p>
    </div>
    `,
    styles: [`
      :host > div {
        border: 2px solid blue;
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
        margin-top: 4rem;
      }
    `]
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit, DoCheck, AfterContentInit,
  AfterContentChecked, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked, OnDestroy {

  @Input() name = '';

  @Output() log = new EventEmitter<string>();

  _verb = 'set';
  _onChangesCounter: number = 0;

  // Only called if there is an [input] variable set by parent.
  ngOnChanges(changes: { [propertyName: string]: SimpleChange }) {
    let changesMsgs: string[] = [];

    for (let propName in changes) {
      if (propName === 'name') {
        let name = changes['name'].currentValue;
        changesMsgs.push(`name ${this._verb} to "${name}"`);
      } else {
        changesMsgs.push(propName + ' ' + this._verb);
      }
    }
    this.log.emit(`onChanges (${this._onChangesCounter++}): ${changesMsgs.join('; ')}`);
    this._verb = 'changed';
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.log.emit(`onInit`);
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    this.log.emit(`doCheck`);
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.log.emit(`afterContentInit`);
  }

  // Called after every change detection check
  // of the component (directive) CONTENT
  // Beware! Called frequently!
  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.log.emit('afterContentChecked');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.log.emit(`afterViewInit`);
  }

  // Called after every change detection check
  // of the component (directive) VIEW
  // Beware! Called frequently!
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.log.emit(`afterViewChecked`);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.log.emit(`onDestroy--child`);
  }
}
```

**Output:**
after all the methods executed

```
onChanges (0): name set to "Alice", onInit, doCheck, afterContentInit, afterContentChecked, afterViewInit, afterViewChecked, doCheck, afterContentChecked, afterViewChecked, onChanges (1): name changed to "Bob", doCheck, afterContentChecked, afterViewChecked, onDestroy--app, onDestroy--child


onChanges (0): name set to "Alice"
onInit
doCheck
afterContentInit
afterContentChecked
afterViewInit
afterViewChecked
doCheck
afterContentChecked
afterViewChecked
onChanges (1): name changed to "Bob"
doCheck
afterContentChecked
afterViewChecked
onDestroy--app
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug, the change detection does not get properly executed after the `ngDestroy` of the child component. If you add a `detectChanges` in the log method you will get the desired effect.

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ebAQyon2P8KSj4lvBAxx)

You should only do it when there is a `ngOnDestroy` event, because if you do it on an `ngDoCheck` or anything similar you'll end up in an infinite loop. It keeps checking, and logging :)

I don't know your use-case though, but if you really need this functionality, you can post a bug report on github